# OctoberCMS login with multiple websites in same browser

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I have been using **OctoberCMS** and I found this very useful indeed.

However, I have come across one strange thing which I want to share with you guys.

I have two different websites in my local server, lets say it **website1** and **website2** and the respective URLs are something like this **http://localhost/website1** and **http://localhost/website2**.

And the Admin URLs are something like this **http://localhost/website1_admin** and **http://localhost/website2_admin**.

Additionally, both the websites have two different databases and those databases are in my local server only. (I am using **XAMPP** on Windows machine).

Now the interesting part is, If I login to **website1** and then I login to **website2**, and go back to **website1**, then I am automatically getting logged out of it.

I just wonder, **why is this happening?** Or, **Is this how OctoberCMS works?** Or **Do I need to make sure something which I have not done yet?**

I just checked **app.php** file from both the websites and checked the `key` values of both the websites and I found those are different.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the cookie created is called `october_session` and it's set on the `localhost` domain. In other words, the same cookie and domain for both of your sites.

You can solve this in one of two ways:

1) You can set up virtual hosts in xampp so that your sites are something like http://website1.localhost and http://website2.localhost -- this way a separate `october_session` cookie will be set on each 'domain'.

2) You can go to `config/session.php` and change the line `'cookie' => 'october_session',` so a different cookie name for each site.

Comment: I recommend using option 2 for @op's current setup

Comment: Easy as you like. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Tschallacka so do I.